# Chuck Norris Joke Teller

Tags: c#, game, regex, api, thread-safety

[image: Main Menu]

[image: Category Menu]

[image: Category List]

[image: Random Name Menu]

[image: Pre-Joke]

[image: Joke]

I've created a command line joke teller which makes Chuck Norris jokes after communicating with the Chuck Norris API.

It also allows you to generate a random person by communicating to the names API and replaces Chuck Norris with that name.

Execution goes like:

1) Asks you if you want a joke

2) Asks you to pick a category

1. Yes -> calls API/Reads file (acts like cache for me) -> shows list
2. No -> picks a random category

3) Asks you to pick a random name

1. Yes -> Calls API
2. No -> keeps the same chuck norris in joke

4) Calls Joke API and replaces Chuck Norris if user asked for random name

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {

        // key and names allowed to remain as static global variable - not eligible for race condition
        static char key;                                     // monitor keyboard strokes
        static Tuple<string, string, string> names;

        const string CHUCK_NORRIS_API_BASE = "https://api.chucknorris.io";
        const string NAME_API_BASE = "http://uinames.com/api/";


        // create a multithreaded approach to speed up execution time
        static async Task Main(String[] args)
          {
            // list of all categories - used to verify if user entered category is acceptable
            string[] categoriesList = null;
            string[] results = null;
            int lastLoad = -1;

            int calls_count = 0;
            // counter to check API calls from both names API and joke API don't exceed certain number (set at 15)
            while (calls_count < 15)
            {
                // Initial Screen
                PrintScreen("Main");

                validateAnswer("Main");

                // Category Screen
                PrintScreen("Category");

                validateAnswer("CategoryOrName");

                string userCategory = null;

                // if category is selected
                if (key == 'c')
                {
                    Tuple<string[], int> catInfo = Tuple.Create(results, lastLoad);
                    catInfo = await getCategories(lastLoad);

                    lastLoad = (int)catInfo?.Item2;
                    categoriesList = parseCategories(catInfo?.Item1, categoriesList);

                    Console.WriteLine("\nChuckie askes you make a selection. Make sure it's written word for word...:");
                    userCategory = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                    validateCategory(userCategory, categoriesList);

                }

                //Randon Name screen
                PrintScreen("Random Name");

                validateAnswer("CategoryOrName");

                // get random name
                if (key == 'r')
                {
                     await GetNames();
                }

                // get the joke and store into results
                String[] joke = await GetRandomJokes(userCategory);
                calls_count++;

                //Pre-Joke Screen
                PrintScreen("Pre-Joke");

                // show joke
                PrintJoke(joke);

            }
            // ends game
            PrintScreen("End");


        }
        // print the joke
        private static void PrintJoke(string[] joke)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", joke));
            Console.WriteLine("\nChuckie hopes you enjoyed your joke. Press any key to go back to main menu...");
            GetEnteredKey(Console.ReadKey());
        }
        // checks user input
        private static void validateAnswer(string stage)
        {
            // checks for valid answer
            switch (stage)
            {
                case "Main":
                    // checks for valid answer
                    while (key != 'y' && key != 'e')
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\nChuckie is not pleased with your invalid answer. Pick 'y' or 'e'");
                        GetEnteredKey(Console.ReadKey());
                    }
                    break;

                case "CategoryOrName":
                    while (key != 'c' && key != 'r' && key != 'e')
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\nChuckie is not pleased with your invalid answer. Pick 'c', 'r', or 'e'");
                        GetEnteredKey(Console.ReadKey());
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }


            // check if user wants to exit
            if (key == 'e')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nChuckie understands. Good day...");
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }

        // different screen displays
        private static void PrintScreen(string screen)
        {
            switch(screen)
            {
                // Main Menu
                case "Main":
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("========================================================");
                    Console.WriteLine("|        =)  Chuck Norris Joke Generator  =)           |");
                    Console.WriteLine("| Do you wish to be elightened by the great chuckie... |");
                    Console.WriteLine("|                    Press y for yes                   |");
                    Console.WriteLine("|                    Press e to exit                   |");
                    Console.WriteLine("========================================================");
                    Console.WriteLine("                                 Made by: Joke Company™ ");
                    GetEnteredKey(Console.ReadKey());
                    break;

                // Category Menu
                case "Category":
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("========================================================");
                    Console.WriteLine("|        =)  Chuck Norris Joke Generator  =)           |");
                    Console.WriteLine("|  Chuckie wonders if you want a category of joke...   |");
                    Console.WriteLine("|              Press c to pick a category              |");
                    Console.WriteLine("|              Press r to get a random category        |");
                    Console.WriteLine("|              Press e to exit                         |");
                    Console.WriteLine("========================================================");
                    Console.WriteLine("                                 Made by: Joke Company™ ");
                    GetEnteredKey(Console.ReadKey());
                    break;

                // Name Menu
                case "Random Name":
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("========================================================");
                    Console.WriteLine("|        =)  Chuck Norris Joke Generator  =)           |");
                    Console.WriteLine("|     Is the joke about chuckie or someone else...     |");
                    Console.WriteLine("|           Press c to make the joke about chuckie     |");
                    Console.WriteLine("|           Press r to get a random name               |");
                    Console.WriteLine("|           Press e to exit                            |");
                    Console.WriteLine("========================================================");
                    Console.WriteLine("                                 Made by: Joke Company™ ");
                    GetEnteredKey(Console.ReadKey());
                    break;

                // Pre-Joke Screen
                case "Pre-Joke":
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("========================================================");
                    Console.WriteLine("|        =)  Chuck Norris Joke Generator  =)           |");
                    Console.WriteLine("|     Chuckie has found your perfect joke...           |");
                    Console.WriteLine("|          Press any key to see it                     |");
                    Console.WriteLine("|                                                      |");
                    Console.WriteLine("|                                                      |");
                    Console.WriteLine("========================================================");
                    Console.WriteLine("                                 Made by: Joke Company™ ");
                    GetEnteredKey(Console.ReadKey());
                    break;

                // Closing Screen
                case "End":
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.Write("\n Chuckie is out of jokes now. Please try again letter :)");
                    break;

                default:
                    break;

            }
        }
        // checks user input for categories
        private static void validateCategory(string category, string[] categories)
        {
            // loop to confirm user enters correct category
            while (!categories.Contains('"' + category + '"'))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nThis is not a category chuckie knows about. Please choose a category from the above list");
                category = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
            }
        }

        //cleans category result into ordered list
        private static string[] parseCategories(string[] results, string[] categories)
        {
            Console.Clear();

            // checks if categories hasn't been previously populated - i.e if program ran before
            if (categories == null) {
                results = results[0].Split('[');
                results = results[1].Split(']');
                categories = results[0].Split(',');
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\nCategories are:");

            //print ordered list of categories
            for (int num_of_cat = 0; num_of_cat < categories.Length; num_of_cat++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n" + num_of_cat.ToString() + "." + categories[num_of_cat]);
            }

            return categories;


        }
        // maps keystroke to standard character - removes error due to case
        private static void GetEnteredKey(ConsoleKeyInfo consoleKeyInfo)
        {
            switch (consoleKeyInfo.Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.C:
                    key = 'c';
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.E:
                    key = 'e';
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.N:
                    key = 'n';
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.R:
                    key = 'r';
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.Y:
                    key = 'y';
                    break;
            }
        }
        // Generates random joke from API
        private static async Task<String[]> GetRandomJokes(string category)
        {
            // creates joke based on first name, and last name and category 
            string[] joke = JsonFeed.GetRandomJokes(CHUCK_NORRIS_API_BASE, names?.Item1, names?.Item2, category);
            // fixes any incorrect pronouns based on random name generated
            return GenderPronounReplace(joke);
        }
        // checks gender pronouns in joke
        private static string[] GenderPronounReplace(string[] joke)
        {
            if (names?.Item3 == "female")
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < joke.Length; i++)
                {
                    switch(joke[i])
                    {
                        case " He ":
                            joke[i] = " She ";
                            break;
                        case " he ":
                            joke[i] = " she ";
                            break;
                        case " His ":
                            joke[i] = " Her ";
                            break;
                        case " his ":
                            joke[i] = " her ";
                            break;
                        case " Him ":
                            joke[i] = " Her ";
                            break;
                        case " him ":
                            joke[i] = " her ";
                            break;
                    }
                } 
            }

            return joke;
        }
        // grabs categories 
        private static async Task <Tuple<String[], int>> getCategories(int lastLoad)
        {
            // save categories to a text file so don't have to call the 
            string[] cat;
            // load categories from file
            if (File.Exists("categories.txt") && lastLoad < 100)
            {
                // read all the categories and last line is count since the number of times text file has been used (in case API updates response to add more categories)
                cat = await File.ReadAllLinesAsync("categories.txt");
                int numLoaded = Int32.Parse(cat[cat.Length - 1]);

                // increment the last updated count and updates the file with new count
                cat[cat.Length - 1] = numLoaded++.ToString();
                await File.WriteAllLinesAsync("categories.txt", cat);
                return Tuple.Create(cat, numLoaded);
            }

            // File has not been created OR > 100 iterations since text file has been updated
            else
            {
                // resets last loaded stat and calls API
                lastLoad = 0;
                cat = JsonFeed.GetCategories(CHUCK_NORRIS_API_BASE);

                // writes list and last Updated from API to file 
                await File.WriteAllLinesAsync("categories.txt", cat);
                await File.AppendAllTextAsync("categories.txt", lastLoad.ToString());
                return Tuple.Create(cat, lastLoad);
            }


           // return  JsonFeed.GetCategories(CHUCK_NORRIS_API_BASE);
        }
        // generates random name
        private static async Task GetNames()
        {
            dynamic result = JsonFeed.Getnames(NAME_API_BASE);
            // stores name, surname, gender
            names = Tuple.Create(result.name.ToString(), result.surname.ToString(), result.gender.ToString());



        }
    }
}
```

It talks to a helper class which handles all the API calls called JsonFeed

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class JsonFeed
    {

        public static string[] GetRandomJokes(string jokeUrl, string firstName, string lastName, string category)
        {
            StringBuilder joke = new StringBuilder("");
            try
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(jokeUrl);
                // TODO: use stringbuilder for this....
                StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder("jokes/random");

                if (category != null)
                {
                    if (url.ToString().Contains('?'))
                        url.Append("&");
                    else url.Append("?");
                    url.Append("category=");
                    url.Append(category);
                }


                //check if word was inside available categories - create array of categories

                 joke.Append(Task.FromResult(client.GetStringAsync(url.ToString()).Result).Result);
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nError");
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                Console.WriteLine("Error Message: {0}", e.Message);
                Environment.Exit(-1);
            }

            if (firstName != null && lastName != null)
            {
                // replace all instances of "chuck" to the first name and "norris" with the last name
                joke.Replace(joke.ToString(), (Regex.Replace(joke.ToString(), "(?i)Chuck", firstName)));
                joke.Replace(joke.ToString(), (Regex.Replace(joke.ToString(), "(?i)Norris", lastName)));
            }

            return new string[] { JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(joke.ToString()).value };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// returns an object that contains name and surname
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="client2"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static dynamic Getnames(string NameAPIUrl)
        {

            try
            {
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(NameAPIUrl);
                var result = client.GetStringAsync("").Result;
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(result);
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nError");
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                Console.WriteLine("Error Message: {0}", e.Message);
                Environment.Exit(-1);
            }
            return " ";

        }

        public static string[] GetCategories(string jokeAPI)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(jokeAPI);

            return new string[] { Task.FromResult(client.GetStringAsync("/jokes/categories").Result).Result };
        }
    }
}
```

I'm still semi-comfortable with best practices and clear documentation so any suggestions in that area or functionality wise, I'm all ears!

Answer (score 3):

Your code is somewhat messy because almost everything is inside a single `Program` class. It can use some abstractions. Few things off the bat:

1) Declare and implement a strongly typed api for your service. For example:

```
interface IChuckService
{
    Joke[] GetRandomJokes(Category category);
    Category[] GetCategories();
    Name[] GetNames();
    //other json-related methods
}
```

2) Declare and implement api for your screens, and create transitions. For example

```
interface IChuckScreen
{
    void Show(IChuckService service);
    //this is an example of "active" state machine (you can use "passive" one instead)
    //return "this" to stay on the screen, or new state to transition away
    IChuckScreen ApplyInput(string input);
}
```

Your program class should probably look like:

```
var service = new ChuckService();
var currentScreen = new MainScreen();
while(true)
{
    currentScreen.Show(service);
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    currentScreen = currentScreen.ApplyInput(input);
}
```

Comment: Good answer. You basically took the crude state machine that OP had in the one class and broke it out to interfaces. Maybe mention this pattern explicitly in the answer? A question: how do you propose to exit the while loop? Using ```Environment.Exit```? Could the IChuckScreen interface have a method flagging for exit that you could use as a condition in the loop? That way, one can easily do cleanup et cetera after the loop.